# How to represent a pointer to a C array in Rust?

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I need an `extern "C"` FFI function in Rust and want to accept an array of fixed size. The C code passes something like:

```c
// C code
extern int(*)[4] call_rust_funct(unsigned char (*)[3]);
....
unsigned char a[] = { 11, 255, 212 };
int(*p)[4] = call_rust_funct(&a);
```

How do I write my Rust function for it ?

```rust
// Pseudo code - DOESN'T COMPILE
pub unsafe extern "C" fn call_rust_funct(_p: *mut u8[3]) -> *mut i32[4] {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new([99i32; 4]))
}
```

Comment: It's a pointer, so you can just use `*mut std::os::raw::c_void` in the extern function signature and transmute it to the correct type.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: That's an answer :)

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Using the correct type gives some type safety than using `void*`, so i would use it only as a last resort. Doesn't rust have a solution for this you mean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use Rust's syntax for fixed size arrays:

```
pub unsafe extern "C" fn call_rust_funct(_p: *mut [u8; 3]) -> *mut [i32; 4] {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new([99i32; 4]))
}
```

You can also always use `*mut std::os::raw::c_void` and transmute it to the correct type.